# Printing html files using VBScript and the FreePDF software

Tags: printing, vbscript

I would like to ask something about VBScript:

Is a way to open a *.html file using the firefox browser or the microsoft Internet Explorer and make it be printed using a special printer which is not the default/standard printer?

The background:
I want to make a *.pdf file using the FreePDF software.

The data source is a local *.html file (without any images).

Could I use the VBScript/VB command "createobject" to create a VB "Application" object?
You know ... you use it to create a new word or excel file ...

I would like to use the following code:

https://srccode.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/vba-pdf-dokumente-mit-free-pdf-xp-erzeugen/

The web site shows a way to send files to the FreePDF software which is 
a pdf printer.

In a first step you create a postscript file and then send it to the FreePDF 
printer.

Example: You could create a new *.ps out of excel like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

Dim strDocument As String
strDocument = "C:\tmp\hello"    ' Name der Ausgabedatei ohne Extension

Dim strPostScript As String
strPostScript = strFile & ".ps"

ws.PrintOut , , , , "FreePDF XP", True, , strPostScript

Dim strFilePdf As String
strFilePdf = Replace(strFilePs, ".ps", ".pdf")

Dim oWsc As Object
Dim oExec As Object

Set oWsc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = oWsc.Exec(FREEPDFEXE & " /q /o " & strFilePdf & " " & strFilePs)

Do While oExec.Status = 0
    Sleep 200
Loop

Kill strFilePs

Debug.Print oExec.Status
```

I tried to realize this using firefox and the iexplorer but it didn't work.

Has anybody new ideas?

It is possible to use this pdf printer software because I mustn't install others on the customers system.
FreePDF is installed on every system we deliver to our customers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 OLECMDID_PRINT                  = 6, 
 OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW           = 7, 
 OLECMDID_PAGESETUP              = 8,
```

**ExecWB Method**

---

Executes a command on an OLE object and returns the status of the command execution using the IOleCommandTarget interface.

**Syntax**

```
object.ExecWB( _
    cmdID As OLECMDID, _
    cmdexecopt As OLECMDEXECOPT, _
    [pvaIn As Variant,] _
    [pvaOut As Variant])
```

Parameters

**cmdID**
Long that represents the identifier of the command to execute. For more information on command identifiers, see MSHTML Command Identifiers.

**cmdexecopt**

OLECMDEXECOPT value that specifies the command options.

**pvaIn**

Optional. A Variant used for specifying command input arguments.

**pvaOut**

Optional. A Variant used for specifying command output arguments.

The OLECMDEXECOPT enumeration specifies command execution options. One value from this enumeration is passed in the nCmdExecOpt argument of IOleCommandTarget::Exec.

```
typedef enum  
{ 
    OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT        = 0, 
    OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER       = 1, 
    OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER    = 2, 
    OLECMDEXECOPT_SHOWHELP         = 3 
} OLECMDEXECOPT;
```

Comment: Hello, I found another way, because I can't select my favourite printer (a PDF printer) when choosing your way. Thanks for your help and have a good weekend! Thomas